# Search functionality across many columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to make a search for a new website I am building. Some of the columns I need to search are int and some are string.

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        var results = db.Properties.Where(x => x.Address.Contains(id)
            || x.Address2.Contains(id)
            || x.City.Contains(id)
            || x.Description.Contains(id)
            || x.GrossLeasableArea.Contains(id) <-- this is an int
            ...
```

So, would it be better to do two separate searches on the different types of column and then join the results? Or is there some other methodology that satisfies this demand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the main question is, how should the value *match* against a numeric column?  For example, if the column has "123" and "2" should match it, then you're essentially treating the column as a string rather than a number.

In that case, just treat it like a string:

```
|| x.GrossLeasableArea.ToString().Contains(id)
```

Comment: I like it... Didn't think of it that way. That makes it all so much easier. thanks!